# How to launch node if param equals true?

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How would I start a node if a parameter equalled a given value? I'm thinking something like this pseudo code:

```
<launch>
    if my_param == true: // PSEUDO CODE - How to properly implement this logic?
         <node name="my_node" pkg="my_package" type="my_node" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

Also, how would I do this using `rosrun` from the command line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376049/how-to-launch-node-if-param-equals-true?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2021-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem using a `bash` script to keep checking until `my_param` changes to `true` to `rosrun` and `kill` the node when needed. This is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
rosparam set my_param false
while :
do
  node_name="/my_node"
  node_search=$(rosnode list | grep $node_name)
  if [ $(rosparam get my_param) == false ]
  then
    if [ "$node_search" == $node_name ]
    then
      rosnode kill $node_name
      fi
  else
    if ! [ "$node_search" == $node_name ]
    then
      rosrun my_package my_node
    fi
  fi
done
```

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2021-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I think the easiest way is by defining an arg. Something like:

```
<arg name="var"/>
```

and then grouping the nodes to start if the argument of var is true. Your launch file should look like:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="var"/>

    <group if="$(arg var)">
       ...nodes to start...
    </group>
</launch>
```

You can then start the nodes from the terminal with:

```
roslaunch you_package launch_file var:=true
```

Let me know if that helps

---

Originally posted by [LR1997](https://answers.ros.org/users/72501/lr1997/) with karma: 43 on 2021-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-04-13**:
Note that any tag can use the `if` attribute.  For example, if you only have one node to launch, you can just put it in the `<node>` tag rather than using a group.  Here's the [roslaunch XML wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#if_and_unless_attributes) for further info.

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-04-13**:
That is very helpful. Two questions... How would I set `var` to a parameter from the parameter server in the launch file or command line? Also, if `var` is `false`, I'd like to keep checking until the parameter that defines it changes to `true` and then start the node. I guess this would be like `while false do nothing`. Is this possible?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2021-04-13**:
I'm wondering if a bash script is needed to achieve what I want. Maybe it would look similar to the following, although I'm unsure of exact syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [$(rosparam get my_param) == ‘false’ or ‘’]; do
if [my_node is running]
then
rosnode kill my_node
fi
done

while [$(rosparam get my_param) == ‘true’]; do
if [my_node is not running]
rosrun my_package my_node // in background so can keep listening for change in my_param value
fi
done
```

What do you think?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-05-07**:
To answer your previous questions:

> How would I set var to a parameter from the parameter server in the launch file or command line?

You can't use a parameter as a variable (AFAIK; there was some discussion, but IDK if it's implemented), but you could set the parameter from the same argument:

```
...
<arg name="my_arg" default="true" />
<param name="my_param" value="$(arg my_arg)" />
<group if="$(arg my_arg)">
  ...
</group>
```

> I'd like to keep checking until the parameter that defines it changes ... Is this possible?

Launch files aren't meant for ongoing behavior, like loops--more just startup.  To keep checking, you'd have to use an external script (as you have), or build the functionality into the node, e.g., using [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure).  You might also consider using something other than a parameter, like a topic or service depending on your use case.  There are pros and cons, so use whatever works for you.